# Load image from gallery to ImageView with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, image, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-gallery

I hope you can help me. Its the first time that i am writing a question here.

I want to select an image from gallery and display it in an ImageView. After closing that activity and reopen it, i want to show the image we previously selected. Select Image ->  Show Image in ImageView -> Save Image Selection -> Close Activity -> Open Activity -> Show Image Selection. 
Hopefully i was clear enough.

The First part of selecting an image from gallery and loading it into the ImageView is working, what is giving me problems is currently i am trying to save the selected image or its path in SharedPreferences/Preferences but it isnt showing when opening the activity again. Saving and Loading with SharedPreferences/Preferences seems to work but, it will not show the picture.

I tried it with: Path, EncodedPath and so on but nothing seemed to work.
What am i doing wrong ?

For opening the gallery:

```
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    gallery.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

For Saving the image:

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("imageURI", imageUri.getEncodedPath());
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

For loading the selected image:

```
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String imageUriString = settings.getString("imageURI", "");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUriString);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(imageUriString)
            //.load(testarrraylogo.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.otto)
            .error(R.drawable.hochbahn)
            // To fit image into imageView
            .fit()
            // To prevent fade animation
            .noFade()
            .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("imageURI", imageUri.getEncodedPath());
editor.commit();
```

Into

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("preference", 
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("imageURI", "uriPathstring");  //Your URI PATH STRING
editor.apply();
```

And Retrieve Like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preference, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String imageUri = prefs.getString("imageURI", null);
```

To load image in Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(imageuri)).into(imageView);
```

Comment: This will never work editor.putString("imageURI", ""); you would save always an empty string

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt seem to work. I used exactly the statements you posted, but in the end i only get a blank image. See @cherif answer above where i said that using placeholder and error image for Picasso returns that error image. What am I doing wrong, tried so many different ways

Comment: I used a few different Variations of the code, but one of them produced an app crash when opening the activity.

Your suggested code 
"Picasso.with(context).load(new File(imageuri)).into(imageView);"
just returns an empty blank image

Picasso.with(GlossarDetailsActivity.this).load(new File(imageUri)).error(R.drawable.XYZ).into(imageView);

results in showing that image in R.drawable.XYZ

Answer (score 0):

The first time that you retrieve the image you are not using Picasso to load the image, you can replace this `imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);` with this `Picasso.with(YourActivity.this).load(imageData).into(imageView)`

Then to save the Uri to the SharedPreferences you can do something like this `editor.putString("imageURI", imageUri.toString);` and then retrieve it with

```
try {
   imageUri = URI.create(myPrefs.getString("imageURI", "defaultString"));
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the question section, even though he is retrieving the String/URI the picture isnt shown. Uri String looks like this:
"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38666"
When I am using placeholder and error in Picasso, it shows for a very short time first the placeholder image and after that it shows the error image.

While debugging i can see that saving and retrieving from the SharedPreferences is working but as mentioned before it shows the selected image when selecting it but not when i want to show that image after retrieving it from Preferences